# How to get the Style Trigger of an WPF element

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I am newbie im WPF, so, i started to develop some test app, my question is how to get the possible properties to be seted in a style trigger, for example, for TextBox i know some properties, like "IsFocused" and "IsMouseOver"

```
 <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
             ...

        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             ...
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

, but, how about other elements? if in the future i need to style another control, how to discover your properties

Answer (score 0):

You read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_properties). (Only [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) apply, so check if they have a section about that.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, VS only provides me intellisense on Setters (<Setter Property="Background"...) on triggers (<Trigger Property="???" Value="???") no.

Comment: @Ewerton: Well, you should know what you want to change/trigger on beforehand anyway, intellisense is just there so you have to type less. If you don't know what properties an object has either read the docs or look at the metadata ("go to definition" in VS, though it does not list inherited members).